# Respond with another site NOT Working on Cloudflare Workers

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

It's working for example .com BUT not working for my desired domain.

Can you please help me to figure out ?

```
addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})
async function handleRequest(request) {
  // Only GET requests work with this proxy.
  if (request.method !== 'GET') return MethodNotAllowed(request)
  return fetch(`https://reveal.magic.link/awst-test`)
}
function MethodNotAllowed(request) {
  return new Response(`Method ${request.method} not allowed.`, {
    status: 405,
    headers: {
      'Allow': 'GET'
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is not working exactly? What problem are you seeing?

Comment: Normal HTML website pages are loading fine, BUT when I'm trying to get any login page like single page application with javascript It's not opening, always loading and loading.

Comment: Is it because the site's HTML contains absolute URLs that are referring to the original location and not being rewritten? You might need to use HTMLRewriter to rewrite URLs...